# linq to sql join on multiple columns using lambda

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

Can someone help me to translate this

```
var query = from s in context.ShoppingMalls
join h in context.Houses
on
new { s.CouncilCode, s.PostCode }
equals
 new { h.CouncilCode, h.PostCode }
select s;
```

into lambda query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 61):

```
var query = context.ShoppingMalls
                   .Join(
                       context.Houses,
                       s => new { s.CouncilCode, s.PostCode },
                       h => new { h.CouncilCode, h.PostCode },
                       (s, h) => s);
```

Comment: edited to give the anonymous objects keys, so that the compiler can infer that the types are the same.

Comment: I don't know where your edit went, but if the names and types aren't the same you can do something like this for both of the join on objects so that the property names match: new { cc = s.CouncilCode, pc = s.PostCode }

Answer (score 23):

Although the example and answer given by @Thomas Levesque works for columns that match, I wanted to also supply the answer if you have columns to join on but they have different names.  This is what I needed for my googling and this question got me close.

The difference of course is the explicit declaration of the columns as a variable to identify on.

```
var query = context.MapKitsToResources
              .Join(
                     context.Resources, 
                     o => new { Id = o.ResourceId, Type = o.ResourceTypeId},
                     i => new { Id = i.Id, Type = TypeId},
                     (o, i) = new { rType : i };
```

Comment: Agree with you for explicit give name to joined columns. Great answer.

Comment: This is the perfect solution to avoid ambiguity between similar columns and match exact columns