# linq to sql join on multiple columns using lambda error

Tags: c#, linq

I tried to translate this query by following the example below:
[linq to sql join on multiple columns using lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317117/linq-to-sql-join-on-multiple-columns-using-lambda)

```
from tabA in this.context.TabA
join tabB in this.context.TabB on
new
{
   field1 = tabA.Soc,
   field2 = tabA.ID
}
equals new
{
   field1 = TabB.Soc,
   field2 = TabB.Code
}
select tabA;
```

with this:

```
var query= this.context.TabA.Join(
    this.context.TabB,
    s => new { s.Soc, s.ID },
    h => new { h.Soc, h.Code },
    (s, h) => s);
```

But the Visual Studio Intellisense reports this error which I did not understand (Join signals me in red):
[image: Visual Studio error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names of the anonymous types have to match.  In the first query you gave them names `field1` and `field2`. The second query will use `Soc`\ `ID` on the first and `Soc`\ `Code` on the second while the `Soc` field will match up the `ID` name will not match the `Code` name.  So the method syntax equivalent of your query syntax would actually be

```
var query= this.context.TabA.Join(
    this.context.TabB,
    s => new { field1 = s.Soc, field2 = s.ID },
    h => new { field1 = h.Soc, field2 = h.Code },
    (s, h) => s);
```

But you only really have to name the second property of the anonymous class since it will take the name `Soc` for the first in both cases.